# What is the input type of GNN?

Tags: graph-neural-network

from reading the articles and papers ,I understood that GNN is used for

1. Node level Prediction
2. Link prediction and
3. graph level prediction

but i am very much confused about GNN's input type

I have a list of questions

1. what is the input type of GNN ? Graphs or numerical data
2. If GNN takes graphs as input then how it is generated ?

Second edit:
By reading another paper i found that GNN takes graphs as input
[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f90xv.png)
Now i had only one question how graph is generated from the input ?

Reference:

1. Jie Zhou a,1, Ganqu Cui a,1, Shengding Hu a, Zhengyan Zhang a, Cheng Yang b, Zhiyuan Liu a,*,
   Lifeng Wang c, Changcheng Li c, Maosong Sun a Graph neural networks: A review of methods and applications "Graph neural networks: A review of methods and applications" AI Open

Comment: The question is : how the input graphs are genrated ?

Comment: My intuition is "The graphs may get genrated by converting the words to vectors and connecting the vectors which are close in a record " say,if we have a news data then each record may consist of serveral words after  basic NLP preprocessing and relationship between these words can be constructed as a graph with the edge values as distance between the vectors and nodes as a vector ,This is just my intuition

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

The input of GNN include objects of different dimensions e.g. properties matrix dimension is [n_nodes, n_node_features], adjacency matrix dimension is [n_nodes, n_nodes] depending of the type of graph-neural-networks.

[Spektral](https://graphneural.network/) is a nice library with good examples of different types of GNN. The examples of how to load the data are also provided.

Here is the example of GNN model created using tensorflow and[1](https://graphneural.network/)

```
class GIN0(Model):
    def __init__(self, channels, n_layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GINConv(channels, epsilon=0, mlp_hidden=[channels, channels])
        self.convs = []
        for _ in range(1, n_layers):
            self.convs.append(
                GINConv(channels, epsilon=0, mlp_hidden=[channels, channels])
            )
        self.pool = GlobalAvgPool()
        self.dense1 = Dense(channels, activation="relu")
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.5)
        self.dense2 = Dense(channels, activation="relu")

    def call(self, inputs):
        x, a, i = inputs
        x = self.conv1([x, a])
        for conv in self.convs:
            x = conv([x, a])
        x = self.pool([x, i])
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return self.dense2(x)
```

You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73265395/tensor-flow-spektral-graph-neural-networks-gradient-descent-issue) for a more complete example of GNN application.